# Passing a long parameter string with special characters

Tags: shell, ksh, getopt

I am not sure whether I am getting a weird error because of how long the parameter string is or because of what is. This is calling a encryption file utility that uses input, output, and public key variables. The input and output variables are the full PATH/FILENAME and the key name is just the installed key name. The full command is 186 characters long. Below is the command.

```
UTILITY.ksh -o /PATH/PATH/PATH/PATH/FILE_OUT.txt -i /PATH/PATH/PATH/PATH/FILE_IN.txt -e "PGP Public Key Company Name, L.L.C. 08 <pgp@companywebsite.com>"
```

Comment: You are surely not getting an error due to the length of the line.  You should put your file names inside double quotes, like `"/PATH/TO/FILE"` : spaces or other special characters could cause problems.  Can you post the actual error message and command line?

Comment: So actually when i saw the column length in notepad++ it was over 256 and i noticed at 256 it truncated. Is there a way to enter a command with parameters over 256 characters

Comment: What OS are you using?  Was the truncation done by your text editor or by the shell?  I use Bash, and just to make sure I just typed a line several hundreds of characters long, and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't see any error message in your posting. Also, why are you tagging the question with *bash* **and** *ksh*? Are you invoking a ksh script from bash?

Comment: It is in KSH and it is truncating after 256 bits so i have to use a lengthy config file instead of just passing in parameters. The error is not a console error but it was not accepting the arguments

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows the file path limit could be the reason for what you are seeing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Those are limits on individual path names, not command lines.

Comment: @chepner does not compute. Read all of the comments on the OP

Comment: The document you linked to only refers to limits on how long a single file path can be; it has nothing to do with how long the combined arguments to a command can be.

Comment: @chepner comment from the OP (from above) "Is there a way to enter a command with parameters over 256 characters – user3753693".. Did you somehow miss it..?